# I love stars - a cryptic message

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

[image: stars]

`7E579O3L57K4782W1H3SXOBDJFLBF8D86MRQV4UA38OHQ25XE793W7QUOXW23KGE009AR97GFKB3DJB5HCY249PYMASA2YJOFDQDMA1PKC`

[image: characters]

<sup><sub>Textual form of above: cyan = 0, 3, 7, 8, A, E, F, M, O, P, Q, X, Y, Z; green = 1, 4, 5, B, C, G, J, N, R, T, W; lilac = 2, 6, 9, D, H, I, K, L, S, U, V</sub></sup>

Hint 1:

> 28º

Hint 2:

> Twin

Hint 3:

> The textual form may be more helpful than you think! (Colors have nothing to do with it.)

Hint 4:

> 5º 6.5h -- 12796

Hint 5:

> Use the letters. (Hint for previous hint.)

Hint 6:

> As a hint for hints 4 and 5, ARCHMAGE -- 7158 would be "GAME"

Hint 7: (still the last hint, but I will wait until the bounty is almost over to post my answer)

> The last three hints refer to "MORSE" (as in Morse Code) and the stars clue leads to "POLLUX." Interpret that how you will!

---

Use the information given above this line to figure it out!

Comment: Wow. This shows a lot of work. +1

Comment: @DrD -- Thanks, I try!

Comment: Agreed, this is an awesome puzzle.

Comment: There's a large star icon at 28 degrees north…

Comment: Trying to match rot13(bar gjb frira avar fvk) with either rot13(ebfrggr) or rot13(svir q fvk svir u). Barking up the right tree?

Comment: @kristinalustig -- Not exactly, no. :):) The 5º 6.5h is a very simple coordinate to direct you somewhere on the picture provided.

Comment: @Voldemort'sWrath right, I got that - do I compare what I found there with the five-digit number?

Comment: @kristinalustig -- Oh, yes... I misinterpreted your question.

Comment: Hi , can i start bounty  or you are going to answer this question ?

Comment: @Swati — Feel free to start a bounty! I can hold off on answering until the bounty is over, then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The image provided with this puzzle and the clues attached to it suggest that what we are dealing with here is a:

> **[POLLUX CIPHER](https://www.dcode.fr/pollux-cipher)** - a cipher where a message has been written in Morse code, and then the dots, dashes and spaces further encoded using numbers and letters.
>
>  Hint 1: The largest star on the **28°** line in the map is POLLUX, in the constellation Gemini.
>  Hint 2: Pollux is a *twin* star (paired with Castor). Castor and Pollux were **twins** in [Greek mythology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castor_and_Pollux) (hence their connection with Gemini - 'the twins' - in astrology).
>  Hint 3: The numbers and letters in cyan represent dots, the greens are dashes, and the lilacs are spaces. The **textual form** is especially useful as these arrangements are the default options for encoding this cipher in some online tools.
>  Hints 4-7: The word written at **5° 6.5h** in the diagram is *MONOCEROS*. If we take characters **1-2-7-9-6** from its name, we spell *MORSE*.

Applying this we find that the sequence of 106 numbers and letters (beginning 7E579...) translates to:

> ..-. .. -. -.. -- . ..- -. -.. . .-. - .... . -... .-.. ..- . -... .- .-. -. --- -. - .... . .-.. . ..-. -

...which in turn translates to:

> **FIND ME UNDER THE BLUE BARN ON THE LEFT**.
>
>  This sounds like the message receiver is being led towards a physical location with which they should be familiar - a blue barn - beneath which they will find their target.

*Alternative solution (because it would be fun to reuse the image):*

> The message could also be parsed as FIND ME UNDER THE BLUE BAR 'N' ON THE LEFT, where 'N' is shorthand for 'AND'. This could be a suggestion that one of the features just below the blue bar and on the left side of the image provided is important, possibly one of the unlabelled stars or the green dot (indicating a nebula) numbered '2392', which goes by the names of [Caldwell 39](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NGC_2392), the Eskimo Nebula, the Clown-Faced Nebula, and the Lion Nebula:
>  [image]
>
>  Alternatively, it could be pointing towards the words even further down the diagram - CANIS MINOR - which also satisfy this description:
>  [image]

Comment: Nicely done! +1 and accepted. The intended answer was a physical location with which receiver is familiar.

Comment: Hi nice answer and congrats for bounty :)

Comment: Thanks @Swati for the bounty :)